# Effective way to write a series of if statements in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a piece of code that I would like to re-write in order for it to be more effective. I am working in Python, and there is not switch-break statement like in Java, but I feel something of a similar structure would work. The piece of code in particular I am talking about is:

```
def update(arm, array1, array2, array3, array4, array5):
    # If the array is empty, add a zero
    if not array1:
        array1.append(0)
    if not array2:
        array2.append(0)
    if not array3:
        array3.append(0)
    if not array4:
        array4.append(0)
    if not array5:
        array5.append(0)
```

In general, what is a good way to avoid writing a series of if-statements like this in Python while also going through and checking each of these arrays for this particular function?

Comment: Each section could be replaced with a loop over the `array`s.

Comment: I don't see how a "switch/break " would help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the function to accept an arbitrary number of arrays with `*args`, then use a `for` loop:

```
def update(arm, *arrays):
    for index, array in enumerate(arrays):
        if not array:
            array.append(0)
        if arm != index:
            array.append(array[-1])
```

Not only that this is shorter, it works on any arbitrary number of arrays passed to `update`, so any of `update(arm, array1)`, `update(arm, array1, array2)`, etc will work.

If for some reason you can't change the function's signature, you can still use a loop but you'll have to hardcode the arrays the loop iterates over.

```
def update(arm, array1, array2, array3, array4, array5,
           array6, array7, array8, array9, array10):
    for index, array in enumerate(array1, array2, array3, array4, array5,
                  array6, array7, array8, array9, array10):
        if not array:
            array.append(0)
        if arm != index:
            array.append(array[-1])
```

Comment: And if you *couldn't* change the signature?

Comment: @ScottHunter then you will probably couldn't change the body as well, no?

Comment: No - for example, the caller might be depending on the arguments having those names.

Comment: @ScottHunter Ok, I added  that case

Comment: the arm section doesn't do what OP asked. The `arm != 0` case only applies to `array1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a decorator for any function where you want empty lists to be assigned a zero element. This will allow you to add the initializations without changing anything inside the function.

```
def noEmptyLists(func):
    def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
        for a in (*args,*kwargs.values()):
            if isinstance(a,list) and not a:
                a.append(0)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return decorated

@noEmptyLists
def update(arm, array1, array2, array3, array4, array5):
    print(arm, array1, array2, array3, array4, array5)


update(1,[],[],[],[],[])

# 1 [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
```